# Why doesn't ajax post call controller method in MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have read almost every question on SO about Ajax Post to controllers. I have tried every single solution that I saw here. Nonetheless, my post still not working. Thus, please do not consider it as a duplicate, at least until I get an answer.

```
public class BlogController : Controller
    {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(BlogElement data)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public class BlogElement
    {
       public string HtmlContent { get; set; }
       public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```

And the Ajax part

```
var data_ = { HtmlContent: "someContent", Date: "someDate" }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Blog/Test",
        dataType: "json",
        data:data_ 
    });
```

Ajax response error says "Not Found". 
Here is my route config. I am actually only using attribute routing.

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

What might be wrong with this configuration?

Comment: What do you have in console? F12 in browser

Comment: Or use Fiddler to see what the request looks like.

Comment: Define "not working". What's the status code of the response?

Comment: @haim770 Response says "not found"

Comment: Show your routing configuration

Comment: @teovankot after making ajax there is no message or error on console

Comment: @haim770 I added my routing config.

Comment: @haim770 I solved the problem thanks to you. I just did added a default routing config.

Comment: If you're "only using attribute routing" and didn't register the default route (`/{controller}/{action}`) nor did you define a `[Route("Blog/Test")]` on your action, what did you expect?

Comment: @haim770 Can you post it as an answer? I believe this basic mistake can be made by other people, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, calling `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` in your `RoutesConfig` doesn't mean the default `{controller}/{action}` route will be registered as well.

Either add it:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Or decorate your action with the appropriate `[Route]` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Blog/Test")]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    // ...
}
```